# How can I combine similar lines a CSV file?

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file that contains city and state values, however, they are not all in the same format. They look like this:

```
city
City
City, State
City, state
city, State
city, state
```

How can I combine these into a single record or count them as being in the same city?

Im using [Google Tables](http://tables.googlelabs.com) to sort the data. Its a big list.

Is sorting/combing these something I can easily with PHP? If so, somebody point me at some general info about where to get started.

Thanks!

Comment: Are all of the city / state names in the same general format? For example are all states listed as a 2 letter code (like `NY` and not `New York`) or is it a mix? What about the cities, is there consistency across city names?

Comment: A quick way to condense most possibilities would be to upper or lowercase all your values, trim all excessive/all whitespace and run a unique pass over your results to bring it all down to something like "City, State", which you can then format back to what you want.

Comment: @dan Yes  there is  consistency in the state names. They are CA, ca, Ca, etc. and sometimes with a . sometimes without, but always not more than 3 chars.

Comment: @scrowler thanks. the making things all caps seems to have worked. trimming the excess made it even better. i didnt realize it could be so easy.

Comment: That **is** the easy part ;) it's dealing with random inconsistencies that makes it hard

Comment: Use strtoupper() or strtolower() to get all the values in the same format.

Comment: This could easily done in PHP. Give some additional details maybe? try to (1) read the file, (2) run through like by line, (3) break each line  using strpos to find the commas , (4) read each field using strtolower